# Firebase login redirect

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue with redirecting a page after login. Overall it works, however for some reason when I try to authenticate for the first time it initially thinks the user is null but then for some reason it redirects the page as if the user is logged in. I'm using the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` method, and currently I have a small line of text that pops up whenever the user credentials is invalid. Whenever I put in the email/password for a correct user, when I hit the signin button for the first time the line of text pops up and then disappears. I have no idea why this happens and I would appreciate any help.

```
//Click Submit button
firebase.auth().signOut()

document.getElementById('signinSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {

    signinEmail = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value
    signinPassword = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(signinEmail, signinPassword).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
      console.log("Failed login + REASON: " + errorMessage + " CODE: " + errorCode)
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

        // console.log(user)
        var wrongEmail = document.getElementById('incorrectEmail'); 

        if(user){
            console.log("redirect")
            wrongEmail.style.display = "none"

            //window.location.href = "dashboard.html";

            }
            else{
                console.log("NULL"); 
                wrongEmail.style.display = "block"
            }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method "**asynchronously** signs in using an email and password." as detailed here in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword.

You should wait the promise to resolve before continuing, like:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(signinEmail, signinPassword)
.then(function(){

  //Succesful, do whatever you want in your page

  console.log("redirect")
  wrongEmail.style.display = "none"
  window.location.href = "dashboard.html";

})
.catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
           console.log(....);
        } else if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
           console.log(....);
        }

      // ... look at all the possible Error codes in the doc to handle the different cases

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your function where you check if the user exists after you sign him in and then you can do that with the `.then` function like that:

```
 var wrongEmail = document.getElementById('incorrectEmail'); 
 //
 //
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(signinEmail,signinPassword)
 .then(function(){
   console.log("redirect")
   wrongEmail.style.display = "none"
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
  console.log("Failed login + REASON: " + errorMessage + " CODE: " + 
  errorCode)
  console.log("NULL"); 
  wrongEmail.style.display = "block"
});
```